# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource when adding new rows to data.sql

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im quite new to spring.Getting the error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource,and Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1.Whole text from console:

```
2021-05-18 09:52:14.706  INFO 15264 --- [           main] r.a.u.f.o.OsaVezbe05Application          : Starting OsaVezbe05Application using Java 11.0.10 on DESKTOP-FFJO4DV with PID 15264 (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OSA5-main\target\classes started by PC in C:\Users\PC\Desktop\OSA5-main)
2021-05-18 09:52:14.706  INFO 15264 --- [           main] r.a.u.f.o.OsaVezbe05Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-05-18 09:52:15.299  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-05-18 09:52:15.299  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.331  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.AdminRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.331  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.ArtikalRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.CategoryRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.OrderItemRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.ProductImageRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.ProductRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.SupplierRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.repository.UserRepository. If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.346  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 42 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.362  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-05-18 09:52:15.362  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-18 09:52:15.409  INFO 15264 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-05-18 09:52:16.081  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-18 09:52:16.096  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-18 09:52:16.096  INFO 15264 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-05-18 09:52:16.190  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-18 09:52:16.190  INFO 15264 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1438 ms
2021-05-18 09:52:16.237  INFO 15264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-05-18 09:52:16.409  INFO 15264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-05-18 09:52:16.409  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:osa_v5'
2021-05-18 09:52:16.565  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-05-18 09:52:16.612  INFO 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
2021-05-18 09:52:16.737  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-05-18 09:52:16.846  INFO 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists admins CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists artikli CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists categories CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists order_items CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists orders CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists product_images CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists products CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists suppliers CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists users CASCADE 
2021-05-18 09:52:17.471 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table admins (admin_id integer generated by default as identity, pasword varchar(255) not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (admin_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table artikli (artikal_id integer generated by default as identity, cena double not null, naziv varchar(255) not null, opis varchar(255) not null, putanja_slike varchar(255) not null, primary key (artikal_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table categories (category_id integer generated by default as identity, cat_desc varchar(255), cat_name varchar(255) not null, parent_cat_id integer, primary key (category_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table order_items (item_id integer generated by default as identity, quantity integer not null, order_id integer not null, product_id integer not null, primary key (item_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table orders (order_id integer generated by default as identity, order_date timestamp not null, user_id integer not null, primary key (order_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table product_images (image_id integer generated by default as identity, content_type varchar(255) not null, image_height integer not null, image_data blob, image_title varchar(255), image_width integer not null, product_id integer not null, primary key (image_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table products (product_id integer generated by default as identity, description varchar(255) not null, prod_name varchar(255) not null, price decimal(19,2) not null, vendor varchar(255) not null, category_id integer not null, supplier_id integer not null, primary key (product_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table suppliers (supplier_id integer generated by default as identity, sup_address varchar(255) not null, sup_name varchar(255) not null, primary key (supplier_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table users (user_id integer generated by default as identity, user_address varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, pasword varchar(255) not null, receive_news boolean not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (user_id))
2021-05-18 09:52:17.487 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table categories add constraint FKk53dr5cgefy7plym1ryv4kst3 foreign key (parent_cat_id) references categories
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table order_items add constraint FKbioxgbv59vetrxe0ejfubep1w foreign key (order_id) references orders
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table order_items add constraint FKocimc7dtr037rh4ls4l95nlfi foreign key (product_id) references products
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table orders add constraint FK32ql8ubntj5uh44ph9659tiih foreign key (user_id) references users
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table product_images add constraint FKqnq71xsohugpqwf3c9gxmsuy foreign key (product_id) references products
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table products add constraint FKog2rp4qthbtt2lfyhfo32lsw9 foreign key (category_id) references categories
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503 DEBUG 15264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table products add constraint FK6i174ixi9087gcvvut45em7fd foreign key (supplier_id) references suppliers
2021-05-18 09:52:17.503  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-05-18 09:52:17.518  INFO 15264 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-05-18 09:52:17.534  WARN 15264 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/OSA5-main/target/classes/data.sql]: create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ARTIKLI" already exists; SQL statement:
create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ) [42101-200]
2021-05-18 09:52:17.534  INFO 15264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-05-18 09:52:17.550  INFO 15264 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-05-18 09:52:17.550  INFO 15264 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-05-18 09:52:17.550  INFO 15264 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-18 09:52:17.565 ERROR 15264 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/OSA5-main/target/classes/data.sql]: create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ARTIKLI" already exists; SQL statement:
create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ) [42101-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:617) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at rs.ac.uns.ftn.osavezbe05.OsaVezbe05Application.main(OsaVezbe05Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/OSA5-main/target/classes/data.sql]: create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ARTIKLI" already exists; SQL statement:
create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ) [42101-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:110) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:444) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ARTIKLI" already exists; SQL statement:
create table artikli ( id int generated by default as identity (start with 1) primary key, naziv varchar(25) not null, opis varchar(25) not null, cena DOUBLE not null, putanjaSlike varchar(50) not null ) [42101-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:89) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 32 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I got this project from my professor and I modified it(just added artikal,the app is supposed to do crud operations which are to be tested in postman).

This is what I have in pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>rs.ac.uns.ftn</groupId>
    <artifactId>osa-vezbe-05</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>osa-vezbe-05</name>
    <description>Osnove softverskih arhitektura 2021 - Vezbe 5</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is what I have in data.sql

```
INSERT INTO admins (username, pasword)
VALUES ('admin', 'admin');

INSERT INTO categories (parent_cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc)
VALUES (NULL, 'Racunari', 'Razni racunari');
INSERT INTO categories (parent_cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc)
VALUES (1, 'Laptop', 'Prenosni racunari');
INSERT INTO categories (parent_cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc)
VALUES (1, 'Desktop', 'Prenosni ali teski racunari');
INSERT INTO categories (parent_cat_id, cat_name, cat_desc)
VALUES (1, 'Server', 'Tesko prenosni racunari');

INSERT INTO suppliers (sup_name, sup_address)
VALUES ('Zika trade', 'Bul. oslobodjenja 1');
INSERT INTO suppliers (sup_name, sup_address)
VALUES ('Zika computers', 'Bul. oslobodjenja 2');
INSERT INTO suppliers (sup_name, sup_address)
VALUES ('Zika soft', 'Bul. oslobodjenja 3');

INSERT INTO products (category_id, supplier_id, prod_name, vendor, description, price)
VALUES (2, 1, 'ThinkPad T61', 'IBM', 'opis', 1000);
INSERT INTO products (category_id, supplier_id, prod_name, vendor, description, price)
VALUES (2, 1, 'Compaq nx9010', 'HP', 'opis', 1200);
INSERT INTO products (category_id, supplier_id, prod_name, vendor, description, price)
VALUES (2, 1, 'Tecra S5', 'Toshiba', 'opis', 1100);

INSERT INTO users (username, pasword, first_name, last_name, user_address, email, receive_news)
VALUES ('chenejac', 'chenejac', 'Dragan', 'Ivanovic', 'Fruskogorska 11', 'chenejac@uns.ac.rs', FALSE);
INSERT INTO users (username, pasword, first_name, last_name, user_address, email, receive_news)
VALUES ('minja', 'minja', 'Milan', 'Vidakovic', 'Fruskogorska 11', 'minja@uns.ac.rs', FALSE);

INSERT INTO artikli (naziv, opis, cena, putanjaSlike)
VALUES ('Naziv artikla 1', 'Opis artikla 1', 100, 'Putanja slike artikla 1')
INSERT INTO artikli (naziv, opis, cena, putanjaSlike)
VALUES ('Naziv artikla 2', 'Opis artikla 2', 200, 'Putanja slike artikla 2')
INSERT INTO artikli (naziv, opis, cena, putanjaSlike)
VALUES ('Naziv artikla 3', 'Opis artikla 3', 300, 'Putanja slike artikla 3')
```

Here is the application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:osa_v5
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create


logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

So the app works fine untill I add last 6 rows.The code I wrote for the artikal files(dto,repository,entity,controller) is the same as the code my professor gave me,no errors what so ever.

Comment: Untill I add last 6 rows to data.sql**

Comment: Did you add any statement that create artikli table again?

Comment: Huh no I didn't,like I said Im pretty new to this. Where do I need to add that?

Comment: @RohithV if you mean about the annotation @Table(name = "artikli") in artikal entity class,I did that.

Comment: Check your `C:/Users/PC/Desktop/OSA5-main/target/classes/data.sql` file. It appears to contain a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson It did contain it,I deleted it but I still get an error :Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #14 of URL [file:/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/OSA5-main/target/classes/data.sql]

Comment: This is the second part of error:INSERT INTO artikli (naziv, opis, cena, putanjaSlike) VALUES ('Naziv artikla 1', 'Opis artikla 1', 100, 'Putanja slike artikla 1') INSERT INTO artikli (naziv, opis, cena, putanjaSlike) VALUES ('Naziv artikla 2', 'Opis artikla 2', 200, 'Putanja slike artikla 2') INSERT INTO artikli (naziv, opis, cena, putanjaSlike) VALUES ('Naziv artikla 3', 'Opis artikla 3', 300, 'Putanja slike artikla 3'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "PUTANJASLIKE" not found;

Comment: In your entity, you are having PUTANJASLIKE column?

Comment: @RohithV yes,but I was trying to make the app work so I tried changing it to putanja_slike.Before that it was 'putanjaSlike'.

Comment: UPDATE
Now im getting: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO ARTIKLI (NAZIV, OPIS, CENA, PUTANJA_SLIKE) VALUES ('Naziv artikla 1', 'Opis artikla 1', 100, 'Putanja slike artikla 1') INSERT[*] INTO ARTIKLI (NAZIV, OPIS, CENA, PUTANJA_SLIKE) VALUES ('Naziv artikla 2', 'Opis artikla 2', 200, 'Putanja slike artikla 2') INSERT INTO ARTIKLI (NAZIV, OPIS, CENA, PUTANJA_SLIKE) VALUES ('Naziv artikla 3', 'Opis artikla 3', 300, 'Putanja slike artikla 3')";